# Generating random mixed multigraph with random edge weights

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The following function generates a random mixed unweighted multigraph:

```
randomMixedUnweightedGraph[vcount_, ecount_] := 
 Graph[Range[vcount], 
  RandomChoice[{UndirectedEdge, DirectedEdge}] @@ # & /@ 
   Table[RandomSample[Range[vcount], 2], {ecount}], 
  VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

E.g., calling randomMixedUnweightedGraph[10, 30] produces (as expected) a random graph with 10 vertices and 30 edges:

[image]

But the trivial extension to a random mixed weighted multigraph:

```
    randomMixedWeightedGraph[vcount_, ecount_] := 
 Graph[Range[vcount], 
  RandomChoice[{UndirectedEdge, DirectedEdge}] @@ # & /@ 
   Table[RandomSample[Range[vcount], 2], {ecount}], 
  VertexLabels -> Automatic, EdgeWeight -> RandomInteger[10, ecount], 
  EdgeLabels -> "EdgeWeight"]
```

does NOT work anymore - it just crashes the kernel with no error message. What is causing this, and how could I get around this?

Comment: The crash is certainly a bug. Please do report it to Wolfram Support: http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/

Comment: The code you show looks entirely reasonable. It's pretty much what I would have written.  Do note that Mathematica doesn't really support any properties for multigraphs.  It is not stated in the documentation that it doesn't, but the property API simply can't distinguish between parallel edges, making it impossible to use with multigraphs. Certain special properties, like edge weights, do sort of work.  But I am not in the least surprised that things go wrong.

Comment: I have been very vocal about these serious limitations, and the urgent need to fix them, but so far not a lot has been done.  I am eagerly waiting for version 12 to see if development of `Graph` has picked up again. If this does not happen by 12, then I think it's reasonable to start looking for other tools than Mathematica to work with graphs.